# Fullscreen applications behave weirdly with applications switcher and custom shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, fullscreen

*Note: I'm unsure if this should be one or two questions, so I'm combining them due to the related nature of the issues I'm experiencing.*

I'm someone who likes to play a lot of videogames, and I'm also someone who likes to automate actions using custom shortcuts and macros on my mouse and keypad. I prefer to play games in fullscreen for a variety of reasons, but I've been experiencing a litany of
(seemingly) related issues with fullscreen apps:

- When I tab out of a fullscreen app, I cannot interact *using the mouse* with any other application. The keyboard works fine, however.
- When I use the application switcher to quickly unfocus a fullscreen app (Alt+Tab once), it switches to the last app I used as I would expect. However, when I try to switch back with a single tap, it instead switches to the app I used two switches ago rather than going back into fullscreen. I have to repeatedly press tab to cycle back to the fullscreen app.
- When I use *any* custom shortcut, including things like volume up/down, it forcibly unfocuses any fullscreen app I'm currently using, unless the application intercepts the shortcut for its own purposes.

Obviously this makes using fullscreen very difficult, and I doubt it's the intended behaviour for most cases (although I can understand if it is for shortcuts that spawn a process). What causes this issue? And if it is intended, how can I change it?

[image: Image of my OS and windowing software versions]

Edit: Thought I should mention that this happens with any fullscreen application, not just games, and if the app sets a custom cursor it remains even when tabbed out of the app.

Comment: Not normal behavior - you should be able to seamlessly switch between full screen apps. You may need to add information about your hardware.

Comment: Could this be caused by hardware? If so then this is probably just another nvidia issue, since my GPU is a nvidia quatro k6000.

Comment: Perhaps yes. You are running X11, though, so that should be proven. Perhaps try a (temporary) new, fresh account to see if the issue also reproduces there. Is this an upgrade? If yes, you may have more success with a fresh install.

Comment: I've reinstalled a few times after upgrades trying to fix this, but the issue has remained since 18.04 no matter how many times I upgrade or reinstall.